# find by nested object value in sequelize with postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to find by a value from a nested array of objects, and I can't make it work.

Let's say I have a table called `Forms`, and this table has an array of objects called `collaborator`.

```js
collaborator: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSONB)
```

A typical json object from this collaborator array would be:

```js
{
 "id": 4,
 "name": 'John'
}
```

I'm trying to find a `Form` based on the `collaborator.name` value. So far I tried this (from various other questions and googling) but it's returning `null`

```js
Form.findOne({
    where: {
        'collaborator.name': 'John'
    }
})
```

I'm reading through this manual from sequelize itself but I think I'm doing something wrong:
https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/querying.html#json

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a [raw query](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/raw-queries.html) using `sequelize.query` function.

`"sequelize": "^5.21.3"` and `postgres:9.6`, E.g.

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, QueryTypes } from 'sequelize';

class Form extends Model {}
Form.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    collaborator: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSONB),
  },
  { sequelize, tableName: 'forms' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await Form.bulkCreate([
      { collaborator: [{ id: 1, name: 'teresa' }] },
      { collaborator: [{ id: 2, name: 'teng' }] },
      { collaborator: [{ id: 3, name: 'slideshowp2' }] },
      {
        collaborator: [
          { id: 4, name: 'John' },
          { id: 5, name: 'Tim' },
        ],
      },
    ]);

    // test
    const data = await sequelize.query(
      `
        SELECT id, collaborator
        FROM   forms f, jsonb_array_elements(to_jsonb(f.collaborator)) obj
        WHERE  obj->>'name' = 'John';
    `,
      { type: QueryTypes.SELECT },
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution result:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "forms" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "forms" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "forms" ("id"  SERIAL , "collaborator" JSONB[], PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'forms' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "forms" ("id","collaborator") VALUES (DEFAULT,ARRAY['{"id":1,"name":"teresa"}']::JSONB[]),(DEFAULT,ARRAY['{"id":2,"name":"teng"}']::JSONB[]),(DEFAULT,ARRAY['{"id":3,"name":"slideshowp2"}']::JSONB[]),(DEFAULT,ARRAY['{"id":4,"name":"John"}','{"id":5,"name":"Tim"}']::JSONB[]) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT id, collaborator
        FROM   forms f, jsonb_array_elements(to_jsonb(f.collaborator)) obj
        WHERE  obj->>'name' = 'John';
[{"id":4,"collaborator":[{"id":4,"name":"John"},{"id":5,"name":"Tim"}]}]
```

Check the database:

```
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from forms;
 id |                             collaborator                             
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"teresa\"}"}
  2 | {"{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"teng\"}"}
  3 | {"{\"id\": 3, \"name\": \"slideshowp2\"}"}
  4 | {"{\"id\": 4, \"name\": \"John\"}","{\"id\": 5, \"name\": \"Tim\"}"}
(4 rows)

node-sequelize-examples=# \d+ forms
                                                Table "public.forms"
    Column    |  Type   |                     Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer | not null default nextval('forms_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 collaborator | jsonb[] |                                                    | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "forms_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct query:

```
const form = await Forms.findOne({
  where: {
    collaborator: {
      name: {
        equals: 'John'
      }
    }
  }
});
```